# Why Doc2vec is slower with multiples cores rather than one?

Tags: multithreading, machine-learning, centos7, gensim, doc2vec

I'm trying to train multiple "documents" (here mostly log format), and the Doc2Vec is taking longer if I'm specifying more than one core (which i have).

My data looks like this:

```
print(len(train_corpus))

7930196
```

```
print(train_corpus[:5])

[TaggedDocument(words=['port', 'ssh'], tags=[0]),
 TaggedDocument(words=['session', 'initialize', 'by', 'client'], tags=[1]),
 TaggedDocument(words=['dfs', 'fsnamesystem', 'block', 'namesystem', 'addstoredblock', 'blockmap', 'update', 'be', 'to', 'blk', 'size'], tags=[2]),
 TaggedDocument(words=['appl', 'selfupdate', 'component', 'amd', 'microsoft', 'windows', 'kernel', 'none', 'elevation', 'lower', 'version', 'revision', 'holder'], tags=[3]),
 TaggedDocument(words=['ramfs', 'tclass', 'blk', 'file'], tags=[4])]
```

I have 8 cores available:

```
print(os.cpu_count())

8
```

I am using gensim 4.1.2, on Centos7. Using this approch (stackoverflow.com/a/37190672/130288), It looks like my BLAS library is OpenBlas, so I setted **OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1** on my bashrc (and could be visible from Jupyter, using !echo $OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1 )

This is my test code :

```
dict_time_workers = dict()
for workers in range(1, 9):

    model =  Doc2Vec(vector_size=20,
                    min_count=1,
                    workers=workers,
                    epochs=1)
    model.build_vocab(train_corpus, update = False)
    t1 = time.time()
    model.train(train_corpus, epochs=1, total_examples=model.corpus_count) 
    dict_time_workers[workers] = time.time() - t1
```

And the variable `dict_time_workers` is equal too :

```
{1: 224.23211407661438, 
2: 273.408652305603, 
3: 313.1667754650116, 
4: 331.1840877532959, 
5: 433.83785605430603,
6: 545.671571969986, 
7: 551.6248495578766, 
8: 548.430994272232}
```

As you can see, the time taking is increasing instead of decreasing. Results seems to be the same with a bigger epochs parameters.
Nothing is running on my Centos7 except this.

If I look at what's happening on my threads using **htop**, I see that the right number of thread are used for each training. But, the more threads are used, less the percentage of usage is (for example, with only one thread, 95% is used, for 2 they both used around 65% of their max power, for 6 threads are 20-25% ...). I suspected an IO issue, but **iotop** showed me that nothing bad is happening at the same disk.

The post seems now to be related to this post
[Not efficiently to use multi-Core CPU for training Doc2vec with gensim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532018/not-efficiently-to-use-multi-core-cpu-for-training-doc2vec-with-gensim) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When getting *no* benefit from extra cores like that, it's likely that the BLAS library you've got installed is already configured to try to use all cores for every bulk array operation. That means that other attempts to engage more cores, like Gensim's `workers` specification, just increase the overhead of contention, when each individual worker thread's individual BLAS callouts also try to use 8 threads.

Depending on the BLAS library in use, its own propensity to use more cores can typically be limited by environment variables named something like `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS` and/or `MKL_NUM_THREADS`.

If you set these to just `1` before your process launches, you may see different, and possibly better, multithreaded behavior.

Note, though: `1` just restores the assumption that every worker-thread only ever engages a single core. Some other mix of BLAS-cores & Gensim-worker-threads might actually achieve the best training throughput & non-contending core-utilization.

And, at least for Gensim `workers`, the actual thread count value achieving the best throughput will vary based on other model parameters that influence the relative amount of calculation time in highly-parallelizable code-blocks versus highly-contended blocks, especially `window`, `vector_size`, & `negative`. And, there's not really a shortcut to finding the best `workers` value except via trial-and-error: observing reported training rates in logs over a few minutes of running. (Though: any rate observed in, say, minutes 2-4 of a abbreviated trial run should be representative of the training rate through the whole corpus over multiple epochs.)

(For any system with at least 4 cores, the optimal value with a classic iterable corpus of `TaggedDocuments` is usually at least 3, no more than the number of cores, but also rarely more than 8-12 threads, due to *other* inherent sources of contention due to both Gensim's approach to fanning out the work among worker-threads, and the Python 'GIL'.)

Other thoughts:

- the `build_vocab()` step is *never* multi-threaded, so benchmarking alternate `workers` values will give a truer readout of their effect by only timing the `train()` step
- ensuring your iterable corpus does as little redundant work (like say IO & tokenization) on each pass can help limit any bottlenecks around the single manager thread doing each epoch's iteration & batching texts to the workers
- the alternate `corpus_file` approach can achieve higher core utilization, up to any number of cores, by assigning each thread its own exclusive range of an input-file. But, it also means (a) your whole corpus must be in one uncompressed space-tokenized plain-text file; (b) your documents only get a single integer `tag` (their line-number); (c) you may be subject to some small as-yet-diagnosed-and-fixed bug(s). (See [project issue #2747](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2757).)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had issue finding which BLAS I have. Using this tutorial on scipy (caam37830.github.io/book/02_linear_algebra/blas_lapack.html), I assumed I have OPENBLAS. So I restarted my Jupyter, starting with !export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1. But sadly, I have the exact same result with my code than before. Do you have any other idea ?

Comment: An export from inside a cell may not affect the currently-running Python interpreter. Check by using `os.environ`. (You *might* be able to set the relevant var there in a way that affects the BLAS library, too, if it's set before that library gets loaded - I'm not sure.)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Put it on my bashrc, and the variable is visible using os.environ. 
But I still have exactly the same result than before, nothing changed.

Comment: I'd not assume you have OpenBLAS based on any online source; you should check your own system, using approaches like those described at <https://stackoverflow.com/a/37190672/130288>, to be sure. (For example, I'm pretty sure any `conda`-based environment tends to install the often-faster Intel MKL.) You can also set the other `MKL_NUM_THREADS` variable just in case. I'd also against suggest tightening your timing to only evaluate the `train()` that uses multiple workers, for starker results, rather than the single-threaded build-vocab.

Comment: Another step that could confirm/refute whether BLAS multithreading is involved: during a 1-workers run, does a tool like `top`/`htop`/etc, show (some periods of) >100% CPU utilization (many cores all highly active)? If so, *something* is effectively using many cores, even though Gensim has only requested one worker thread. Note also: a tiny `vector_size=20` value somewhat limits the potential speedups from BLAS optimizations & threading, as it means relatively-less time in the bulk calculation blocks that gain the most.

Comment: If tinkering with the BLAS threads values don't change the observed behavior at all, please extend your question with the latest results for all `workers` values in both the original and explicitly-set THREADS=1 conditions.

Comment: Following your advice, I updated a lot the initial question.

Comment: Without seeing it live, it's hard to be sure how to interpret `htop` info, but the vague pattenr you've described – ower utilization per thread with more threads – is roughly what's expected in the classic corpus-iterable mode, even when more threads are helpgin, because of inherent contention there. I'm still not sure you tried the right env var, given how many reports there are of people being unsure which BLAS library is active. You could also try to explicitly use MKL (such as via a `conda` install) to improve this & other perf issues. (It's typically faster than OpenBLAS.)

Comment: Note that given your discreption of the corpus as being completely object-in-memory, there should be essentially *zero* IO during your `train()` call, when using the list iterable corpus. IO would only be a contributor if your `train_corpus` were something other than a list, streaming data from a volume, or if you'd somehow started relying on swapped virtual memory (a big no-no for an algorithm like this).

Comment: Given your updates, it remains possible the tiny `vector_size=20` is a major contributor to the slowdown; by making the parallelizable bulk array ops shorter, that forceloses much potential parallelism. If your vocabulary is large enough I'd try a larger `vector_size`. (With 10s of thousands of unique terms, perhaps `vector_size=100`; with hundreds-of-thousands or more, `vector_size=300`.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the best way to fully use the core is to use the parameter **corpus_file** of doc2vec.

Doing the same bench, the result looks like :

`{1: 114.58889961242676, 2: 82.8250150680542, 3: 71.52109575271606, 4: 67.1010684967041, 5: 75.96869373321533, 6: 100.68377351760864, 7: 116.7901406288147, 8: 139.53436756134033}`

The thread seems to be useful, in my case 4 are the best.
Still strange that the "regular" doc2vec is not that great at parallelizing

Comment: Glad the `corpus_file` suggestion helped! If >4 is worse than 4, you might not have 8 true physical cores, but 8 simulated 'hyperthreading' cores on 4 physical cores. In such a case, stuff that could theoretically saturate 8 cores will actually do worse, because instead of 4 cores ideally-saturated by exactly 4 threads facing no io/coordination-blocking, you've got 8 max-intensity threads fighting for the 4 cores.

Comment: @gojomo Yep, I think that you're right. I'll stop there since I got what I want, thanks for all the help. Time to tune the model !

Comment: FYI - here's an answer on a way to check if your true number of physical cores is only 4: <https://stackoverflow.com/a/36540625/130288 >. Good luck!